# Trouble using res.end() in a node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

so, below is a code snippet from my server.js file. When running, and I send a URL with a message, the res.end() causes the view to render a blank page.

When I comment out the res.end() command, the view displays all of the messages, but the browser waits and waits for the signal that the response from the server is complete.

I get that you can use res.end() and put data in the parens, to be transmitted and rendered by the view.

What I expect to happen is that with no args, it will just leave the view alone, but the empty args in the parens is manifesting as an empty view.

How do I indicate that the response is complete without deleting the data on the view?

server.js

```
var   http = require('http'),
      url = require('url'),
      fs = require('fs');

var   messages = ["testing"];
var   clients = [];

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
  var url_parts = url.parse(req.url);
  console.log(url_parts);
   if(url_parts.pathname == '/') {
      // file serving
      fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, data) {
        // console.log(data);
         res.end(data);
      });
   } else if(url_parts.pathname.substr(0,5) == '/poll'){
    //polling code
    var count = url_parts.pathname.replace(/[^0-9]*/,'');
    console.log(count);
    if(messages.length > count){
      res.end(JSON.stringify({
        count: messages.length,
        append: messages.slice(count).join("\n")+"\n"
      }));
    } else {
      clients.push(res);
    }
   } else if(url_parts.pathname.substr(0, 5) == '/msg/') {
  // message receiving
  var msg = unescape(url_parts.pathname.substr(5));
  messages.push(msg);
  while(clients.length > 0) {
    var client = clients.pop();
    client.end(JSON.stringify({
      count: messages.length,
      append: msg+"\n"
    }));
  }
  // res.end(); //if left in, this renders an empty page, if removed,
  // client keeps waiting....
  }
  }).listen(8080, 'localhost');
  console.log('server running!');
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var counter = 0;
    var poll = function() {
      $.getJSON('/poll/'+counter, function(response) {
         counter = response.count;
         var elem = $('#output');
         elem.text(elem.text() + response.append);
         //elem.text(counter);
         poll();
      });
    }
    poll();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id="output" style="width: 90%; height: 90%;">
  </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

I have looked in the docs, but I don't see anything specific about using .end() method with empty args to signify and end without passing data to be rendered. I have googled this, but I don't have an answer yet.

Comment: Can you post full working code?

Comment: `When I comment out the res.end() command, the view displays all of the messages`, how did you do that? Your code does not show any logic of `client.end()`

Comment: @abhyudit-jain, full working code for the server.js file is now posted above, thanks in advance for your thoughts

Comment: @abhyudit-jain I added html file too

Comment: @shaochuancs I don't understand your comment, can you rephrase? All I know is that if I comment out res.end(), the messages will display but the browser continues to expect more data.

Comment: @CaptainChaos your previous code does show what `clients` is. I understand it is a plain array now. Trying to figure out the root cause of your problem...

Comment: @shaochuancs thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

My understand of your problem is:

1. You have an HTML page (`index.html`), which has a `textarea` displaying all messages submitted by user. After one message is received and displayed, it will send the request for next message immediately (`/poll/<n>`).
2. To accept user's input for latest message, you open an API (`/msg/<message>`). When an HTTP request is sent to this API, server will extract the message, and return this message to `/poll/<n>` sent in step 1.
3. However, as HTML page (`index.html`) and the request to `/msg/<message>` happens in the same browser window, you can't let the http handler of `/msg/<message>` in node.js invoke `res.end()`, because in that case, the browser window will render the HTTP response of `/msg/<message>` request (blank page). Actually, you can't make the `res` return 200 OK, whatever data it returns. You can't make `res` fail the `/msg/<message>` request either (using `req.destroy()`), because in that case the browser window will render a failure/broken page, which is worse.
4. Unfortunately, you can't make `res` of `/msg/<message>` in node.js keep pending either. Although it will update `index.html`, the browser window will keep waiting...

The root cause of your problem is: browser window resource conflict between `index.html` and `/msg/<message>` response -- as long as `/msg/<message>`  request is sent by using `index.html` window's URL bar, whenever its response is sent back, the window content (`index.html`) will be cleaned.

One solution is: using Ajax to send `/msg/<message>`. In this way, there would be no conflict for window resource. Example code is listed below:

```
<body>
  <textarea id="output" style="width: 90%; height: 90%;">
  </textarea>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="msg">
    <button type="button" onclick="submitMsg()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</body>

window.submitMsg = function() {
  var msg = $('#msg').val();
  $.getJSON('/msg/' + msg, function(res) {
    $('#msg').val('');
    console.log('message sent.');
  });
}
```

EDIT:
Another simpler solution is: open `index.html` in one browser window, and open `/msg/<message>` in another one (use `res.end('message received successfully')` to indicate message receiving result).

Comment: I will have to take a look at this when home. Seems reasonable. I know that when I open multiple browsers, then send a message from one, the other browsers update properly, and that's good, but the browser I send from gets wiped clean.

Comment: @CaptainChaos is your problem solved? If yes, maybe you can "accept" one of the answers?

Comment: I got busy with something else. I haven't found an answer yet, but haven't tried everything recommended. I will get back to this in a week or so. Thanks for your patience, and for the reminder

Answer (score 0):

Do a res.json({success:"true"}) instead. The reason being is because res.end inherently thinks the client was sent a view prior to the stream being closed. With res.json() you can send any generic data, without an implied view being expected as well as close out the stream on client and server side.

Comment: I got the following error: TypeError: res.json is not a function. Is that because .JSON is an express function, not a node function? I don't require Express in this app (not yet at least), just http

Answer (score 0):

Move `res.end()` inside `while` loop

```
while (clients.length > 0) {
    var client = clients.pop();
    client.end(JSON.stringify({
        count : messages.length,
        append : msg + "\n"
    }));
    if(!clients.length) {
        res.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, same problem as with my code above, when a call is made to /msg/message, for example, I can se that it is posted, but then it is removed, presumably by the empty .end() command. Thanks for your help. Any other ideas?